# MSAccess: Hidden fields only appear after clicking ok twice in combobox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I created this multifield combobox under the field of Type in a data entry form. Ideally, users can click on the relevant type(s) and the respective fields for what they selected will appear. So for example if I choose Type A and Type B, then below the initially hidden fields under Type A and B will appear, which they will then fill in.

My code works, but in a rather odd fashion, after ticking the box, and clicking ok, I would have to click ok again for the fields to appear. An example of the code is below,

```
Private Sub Incident_Type_Click()
If Incident_Type.Text = "" Then 
  Me.C_Threat.Visible = False 

End If

If Incident_Type.Text = "Cybersecurity" Then 
   Me.C_Threat.Visible = True
End If
```

I suspect it might be because I used `.Text` instead of `.value`. However when using `.Value`, I get a error 13 mismatch error that I haven't been able to debug.

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Try `C_Threat.Visible = Incident_Type.Column(0) = "Cybersecurity"`. Just change the column index.

Comment: @KostasK. I can't get the code to work when it's change to `.value`. I would get the error message of 13 Mismatch error.

Comment: @KostasK. Seems to solve the issue, however, if i were to untick the box, i would still have to click ok twice for it to mask the field again. Is it something to do with the blank string text at the beginning?

Comment: Not sure but you don't need that, only the line in my comment should be in the method body.

Comment: @KostasK. ok sure, additionally, i realised an issue. because this combobox is multifield, where I can select more than 1 type, the code you provided, doesn't seem to work when there's more than 1 field.

Comment: Oh, yeah it wont work properly. You will need to loop through the selected items and check if the word exists.

Comment: @KostasK. sorry, would you mind being more specific on what you mean by selected items? is it using .selected? apologies new to vba

Comment: If combobox is multi-select then it is bound to a multi-value field. There is no 'selected list' with a multi-select combobox - there is a hidden table that can be queried. I NEVER use multi-value field.

Comment: ^^^ this. Regular combobox does not allow multiselect unless we are talking for a listbox. @June7 multi-value fields are a nightmare!

Comment: @June7 trying multifield list, but not sure why the bosses didn't prefer it, but regardless, managed to find a workaround. Thanks for the help!